# How can I upload files to a browser from remote?

Tags: ssh, file-upload, remote-access

I am quite new into the world of remote connections so I don't really know what is possible and what is not.

I have established connection to a remote pc over ssh. I need a large file from this remote to be uploaded to a file-sender internet page. One way is to simply copy the file from remote to my local and subsequently upload from local but I want to speed up this task. I am wondering if there is a (safe) way to 'browse' through files or select files located on remote when selecting files in the upload website?

For illustration, think of selecting an image for Google's search by image and this image is located on my remote computer. After hitting the 'select a file' button, want to be able to pick a file from my remote computer to have it uploaded via this button. My question is not how to upload a file to a remote server.

The remote computer does not have any browser or so installed, it is just a collection of file directories and media disk connections that I can access. (I don't have all the details but this is all I know) That's why using the upload website through an internet browser, for example with a GUI as Ubuntu's Genome, is not an option.

Also, the upload internet page is not a specific url to upload to, so a solution like wget does not work either.

I have tried googling with the question in my title but this leads to me to solutions like Chrome's Secure Shell. I don't completely understand what I can do with it but it feels like that does not allow me to do what I want.

fyi, I work on Windows (using Ubuntu occasionally)

Comment: Welcome to So, please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a better question here.

Comment: Thank you, is there anything in specific unclear about my question? I am happy to edit it

Comment: It's better to mention some search or code you use that doesn't make you find the answer.

Comment: To help you with your question. you can use FTP to upload files on the ubuntu server as well. take a look at [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-and-use-ftp-server-in-ubuntu-linux), which may be helpful.

Comment: thank you, your hint on  FTP lead me to trying the solution on https://kb.iu.edu/d/adae with WinSCP. I'll let you know if it works

Comment: selecting the file on remote in WinSCP and dragging to the internet page's upload button does not work, it only copies the file from remote to temporary location on my local

Comment: @time123 so you crate FTP account on the Linux server? did you try FileZilla for the FTP client as well?

Comment: No it does not allow me to do what I want. Updated my question for a toy example of what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer on: http://makerlab.cs.hku.hk/index.php/en/mapping-network-drive-over-ssh-in-windows  .
Need to install WinSfp and SSHFS-Win. Then in windows file browser, mount a new network drive with Folder: \sshfs\username@domain . I can now browse the files through the windows file browser and thus can select files for upload